# Appending hotspots on top of an exisiting image. JS and JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

What i'm trying to do is append hotspots on top of an existing image. As of right now this code appends the new div and image but does so next to the image and not on top of it. I'm new to javascript and jquery so any help is appreciated.

```
//build data structure to store coordinates and content. 
var product_hotspots = new Array();
product_hotspots[0] = {x: 200, y:200, content: "This is test content"}
product_hotspots[1] = {x: 500, y:500, content: "This is more test content"}
product_hotspots[2] = {x: 400, y:400, content: "This is even more test content"}

//loop through each hotspot. 
$(product_hotspots).each(function(idx) {
    //append a new div to #product_image for each hotspot with the following format: 
    var $newdiv1 = $('<div id="bullet" style="position: absolute; top: product_hotspot[idx].x; left: product_hotspot[idx].y" data-content="product_hotspot[idx].content"></div>');
    var $image1 = $('<img src="images/hotspot.png"/>');


    $("#product_image").append($newdiv1,$image1);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your concatenation of the properties taken from object is incorrect. You are missing quotes that tell javascript they aren't strings and values of a javascript object

Try

```
$('<div id="bullet" style="position: absolute; top:'+product_hotspot[idx].x+'px; left:'+product_hotspot[idx].y+'px" data-content="'+product_hotspot[idx].content+'"></div>');
```

Notice the syntax highlighting of the `product_hotpsot` items reflecting they are not string

NOTE: I believe you have `x` and `y` in wrong positions within the `style`. Normally `x` is `left` not `top`

Comment: No more script errors but the images are still not on top of the existing image that is placed on the webpage first. They show up on the side of the existing image. **By on TOP I mean overlapping the original image.**

Comment: inspect the element html and css in browser console. Any out of place quote or missing space in html will cause it to render incorrectly. Hard to troubleshoot without being able to inspect in console. Overlapping could be a lack of space.. I have no idea what page or elements look like

Comment: Oooooooooh... just noticed importnt part that's missing.... need to add `px` after the `top` and `left` values. I've done same thing before myself. Without the units browser doesn't know how to interpret and ignores the `top` and `left`. Make sure `px` is in string part, with no leading space. I modified answer also

Comment: var $newdiv1 = $('<div id="bullet" style="position: absolute; left:'+product_hotspots[idx].x+'px ; top:'+product_hotspots[idx].y+'px" data-content="'+product_hotspots[idx].content+'px"></div>');

Comment: That's the new code with all the things you asked and I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: create a demo with enough css to replicate it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: notice another thing... `$(product_hotspots).each(function(idx) {` should be `$.each(product_hotspots,function(idx) {`

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: paste html in html block, css in css block, js in js block. Select jQuery from framework and click run. If no script erorrs clcik save and paste link here

Comment: Are you going to be able to see the result? The images are saved on my computer.

Comment: I did notice after inspecting elements that the div does get placed at the x and y coordinates but the pictures get placed next to the larger image.

Comment: sounds like a css issue with images... look at css rules for the image inside div

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean.

Comment: use browser console to inspect css rules that apply to the image element. Can see rule rank for every element in the page

Comment: sorry... I didn't notice you posted a fiddle. Great! Problem is images are not inside the new DIV that gets the position set .. try this  http://jsfiddle.net/TYuW2/2/

Comment: forgot to change it but can't duplicate ID in a page... must be unique by definition

Comment: var $newdiv1 = $('<div id="bullet" style="position: absolute; left:'+product_hotspots[idx].x+'px ; top:'+product_hotspots[idx].y+'px" data-content="'+product_hotspots[idx].content+'px"><img src="images/hotspot.png"/></div>');

Comment: That does what I need it to do. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: keep link to fiddle handy for next time...will save a lot of time when we can see resulting problems. Much faster to spot in browser console